# SpeechToTextV1 - Missing required modules SSCZLib, SSCommonCrypto

Tags: xcode, speech-to-text, ibm-watson

I am working on XCode 9.1 project that uses IBM Watson swift-sdk SpeechToTextV1 package. After upgrading swift-sdk to the version 0.19.0 and building XCode project the compiler error has occured: Missing required modules: 'SSCZLib', 'SSCommonCrypto' pointing to the import SpeechToTextV1 statement. swift-sdk updated via Carthage. 
Cartfile content: github "watson-developer-cloud/swift-sdk".
command line update: carthage update --platform ios --no-use-binaries.

How can I include SSCZLib and SSCommonCrypto modules into XCode project?

Please help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Use `carthage update --platform iOS --no-use-binaries`. It takes a while, but it works.

Comment: I tried using with --no-build to save time, but it did not work. Using your command solved for me

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid that I haven't been able to replicate the problem on my machine. I started with a new, empty Xcode project and was able to transcribe audio with the Speech to Text service.

I uploaded my app [here](https://ibm.box.com/s/sl7ht9cn9wt8aeujtvzvunwu0s1kufor). Can you try downloading it, adding your Speech to Text credentials, and running the app?

Comment: Hi Glenn - I'm also having this issue. You can clone project and compile and see it here: https://github.com/etayluz/WatsonDemo. I have tried to compile with --no-use-binaries but this does NOT help

Answer (score 0):

For me - in addition to building the library using --no-use-binaries flag - I also had to ensure that under my target's

- Build Phases->Embed Frameworks
- Build Phases->Link Binary with Libraries

SpeechToTextV1.framework is included

In addition - I found that these two files made all the difference inside the Carthage folder:

- Carthage/Checkouts/ios-sdk/Source/SupportingFiles/Dependencies/Starscream/zlib/include.h
- Carthage/Checkouts/ios-sdk/Source/SupportingFiles/Dependencies/Starscream/zlib/module.modulemap

I could only get this to work after my project was directly referencing the Carthage folder. Deleting either of these two files caused the error to return.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that the newly compiled frameworks are the ones being used.  Carthage does not place the frameworks in a custom location that is referenced in the project or workspace.

Answer (score 0):

The [v0.21.0 release](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/swift-sdk/releases/tag/v0.21.0) of the Watson Swift SDK fixes this issue. You should no longer have to add a link to the `zlib` folder in your project settings. However, you will need to copy `Starscream.framework` into your application in the same way that other frameworks are copied.

The solution was to externalize the Starscream dependency. Adding Starscream as a recursive dependency for the Swift SDK allows it to build independently with its own environment. When the Starscream library is copied into your application, it should automatically include the `SSCZLib` and `SSCommonCrypto` dependencies.

We test each SDK before it's release, but this problem slipped past us. Our test machine happens to have other software that adds `SSCZLib` and `SSCommonCrypto` to the path, making it available to the Xcode build. It wasn't until we refreshed the machine with a new macOS install that we were able to replicate the problem. And with v0.21.0, that problem has been solved.

Sorry for your trouble and thank you for your patience while we tracked down the solution!